# Best way to avoid javascript's executing

Tags: php, javascript, security

I'm using PHP and Zend Framework in my application. User can enter some HTML and admin can see this HTML. I want to avoid XSS injection. All HTML should me shown as is except any javascript. I tried to remove `script` tags but it is unsafe. User can add javascript to `onclick` or other events.

Thanks.

Comment: in this case i'd probably use some kind of an input cleaner/purifier. For example htmLawed:
http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to sanitize user input like this from XSS, I'd look into using [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Removing only script tags is not enough, you miss out any javascript inline that people can add, among other things.

[HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) however will remove it all for you. From their site:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant HTML filter library written in
>   PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious code (better
>   known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive
>   whitelist, it will also make sure your documents are standards
>   compliant, something only achievable with a comprehensive knowledge of
>   W3C's specifications.

Comment: Nice tool. Thanks. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to manually cover all vulnerabilities.

Start by removing script tags, then run regular expressions on the `on` events (onclick, onhover...) and remove those as well. There's more offcourse...

CodeIgniter (other frameworks as well probably) has a function [xss_clean()](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php#L255), you might have a look at that one to see what they do.